# Using mathjax on a computer

Tags: education

Are there any apps or downloadable programs that allow the use of mathjax on a computer - making it easier to type up equations and problems?

Comment: Have you tried to query the web? Are you looking for free tools? What OS?

Comment: I am looking for free tools. Windows os

Comment: I wrote an app in c# where you put the latex in a textbox, pressed the button & then it would display the equation. Is this the kind of thing your looking for ... you need to install  WpfMath in visual studio.

Comment: or just do it in a browser http://mathb.in/

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools addressing the need with variety of options. Take a look [Wiki-Compare-LaTex Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors), but this list is not complete. Also consider: [LaTex Project](https://www.latex-project.org/get/).

Important: If you ever download a free software, you need to consider that it could contain malware. Protect your data before installing/unzipping the software, after you have checked it using a strong checker such as [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).